# How can I check what children were passed to a react component with enzyme and mocha?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Let's say I have the following component instantiations:

```
<ParentComponentWhichIsTested>
    <Expand trigger={<span>Click me to expand this element</span>}>
        <ComponentReference1></ComponentReference1>
    </Expand>

    <Expand trigger={<span>Click me to expand this element</span>}>
        <ComponentReference2></ComponentReference1>
    </Expand> 
</ParentComponentWhichIsTested>
```

And the render method of `Expand` looks like this:

```
//in expand
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <ExpandTrigger>{trigger}</ExpandTrigger>
            <ExpandContent>{this.props.children}</ExpandContent>
        </div>
    );

}
```

I want to assert that the type of content component for the first Expand instance was `ComponentReference1` and that for the second instance it was `ComponentReference2`.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

const comp = mount(...ParentComponentWhichIsTested...)
console.log(comp.props().children); //will be 2, the trigger and content nodes, but I want to see that I actually *sent* a child, not what the component rendered.
```

How can I check the send children? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something seems out of whack there. If `mount` is from Enzyme, then `comp` should be a `ReactWrapper` and `comp.props` should be a function.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, my bad. I meant to write `comp.prop('children')` or `comp.props().children`.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate your results. In that scenario I am getting the `Expand` elements. Even if that didn't work you could store the unwrapped `ParentComponentWhichIsTested` element and check its `props.children`.

Comment: I ended up using `.find(someRelevantSelector)` and length to assert that the two expand elements do indeed contain the `ComponentReference1` and `ComponentReference2` as children. I think the best way I can formulate the issue I'm having is this: *if a component changes it's received props.children then the enzyme `.prop('children')` will return the changed children, not the received children.* I will try to replicate this by creating a component that ignores it's passed down children and sets new ones, and see what the `.prop('children')` gives me.

Comment: Update: it's an issue somehere in my code, enzyme worked fine in an isolated test